# Getting percentages that are comparable among word lists of different lengths

Tags: percentages

I am doing research in which I have 8 foreign language vocabulary word lists (FLV). Then I have one big list of words that my students are studying. I'm calculating percentages of  each of the foreign vocabulary lists that are on the one student vocabulary list. Then, I'm also calculating the percentage of each of the foreign vocabulary lists that is on the student vocabulary list. So, my data looks like this below:
[FLV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7C60.png)
So, my problem is this: Each of the FLVs have different numbers of words. So, of course, a really big list, like the one with 18,000+ words is more likely to contain a higher percentage of my students' words than the list with only 1,259 words. So, how can I make my percentages more meaningful, or "equal" to each other? How can I compare my percentages equally so that, no matter how many words are on the FLV, the percentages will be comparable? I hope my question is clear. Thanks for any thoughts you can provide!

Answer (score 0):

multiply by the percentage size, of the list you are comparing.  In the 18000 to 1259 comparison, since 1259 is just under 7% of 18000, you get that 20% of the smaller list, is roughly 1.4% of the larger list. Because, that's what 7% of 20% of something is.

Comment: thanks a lot for taking the time to answer. I'm not sure I understand exactly what you mean, but I understand what you're saying about percentages of each list. I appreciate your help.